# How to create different states in a game i.e. gameStatePlaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm trying to create different states in a game I'm making so I can use the timer to check different things i.e. gameover etc.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
typedef enum:NSInteger {
    gameStateBegin,
    gameStatePlaying,
    gameStateOver,
    gameStateWining
}gameState;
```

And

```
- (void)onTimer {
    switch (self.state) {
        case gameStateBegin: {
            startTime = currentTime;
            self.state = gameStatePlaying;
            break;
        }
        case gameStatePlaying: {
            countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime - startTime);
            if (countDownInt>0) {
                countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TIME REMAINING: %i", countDownInt];
            }
            else if (countDownInt <= 0) {
                self.state = gameStateOver;
            }
            break;
        }
        case gameStateOver: {
            self.state = gameStateWining;
            [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
                countDown.text = @"";
            }],
                                                 [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
                //transition

            }],
                                                 ]]];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But it's giving me a hard time telling me I need a property for state. So I created the following property:

@property gameState *state;

But that didn't work and it said "Statement requires expression of integer type ('gameState *' invalid)

So I'm completely stumped. I don't even know if I'm approaching this the right way.

**Can anyone figure out what kind of property I can make to get this switch working in this method. 
Also, if anyone has a better way of doing this please suggest!!**

Comment: You need to be totally familiar with having a singleton, to make a state machine.  Get yourself a nice singleton and keep the state in there.

Comment: Ehi, we posted solutions, so please sign the right answer and the argument is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should to use this new iOS MACRO: `NS_ENUM`

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GameState) {
    GameStateBegin,
    GameStatePlaying,
    GameStateOver,
    GameStateWining
};
```

This approach is better for the compiler type checking rather than the classic `enum`.

For the property remove the * because is not an object but a primitive `int`:

```
@property (nonatomic) GameState state;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, all the errors are cleared. There is a problem now though, it doesn't do anything. Any idea where to call the onTimer method? I thought in the initWithSize method, but that didn't work, so I also tried when the user taps the start button but it still didn't work

Comment: Nvm got it. Thanks though awsome answer!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *. NSIntegers don't have pointers :)

```
@property (nonatomic) gameState state;
```

Also, you seem to be doubting, but you're doing it the right way.